# error: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default

Tags: intel, odroid, realsense

I've been trying to set up an intel realsense D415 on an Odroid XU4 and keep on running into the same error. As I am going through the commands at https://github.com/IntelRealSense/librealsense/blob/development/doc/distribution_linux.md, the below error pops up when I try to sudo apt-get update

```
odroid@odroid:~$ sudo apt-get update
Get:1 http://deb.odroid.in/5422-s bionic InRelease [1701 B]
Hit:2 http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports bionic InRelease                    
Hit:3 http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports bionic-updates InRelease            
Hit:4 http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu bionic InRelease                     
Hit:5 http://ppa.launchpad.net/apt-fast/stable/ubuntu bionic InRelease         
Hit:6 http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports bionic-backports InRelease          
Err:7 http://realsense-hw-public.s3.amazonaws.com/Debian/apt-repo xenial InRelease
403  Forbidden [IP: 52.218.80.49 80]
Hit:8 http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports bionic-security InRelease    
Err:9 http://realsense-alm-public.s3.amazonaws.com/apt-repo xenial InRelease
403  Forbidden [IP: 52.218.80.49 80]
Reading package lists... Done                      
E: Failed to fetch http://realsense-hw-public.s3.amazonaws.com/Debian/apt-repo/dists/xenial/InRelease  403  Forbidden [IP: 52.218.80.49 80]
E: The repository 'http://realsense-hw-public.s3.amazonaws.com/Debian/apt-repo xenial InRelease' is not signed.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
E: Failed to fetch http://realsense-alm-public.s3.amazonaws.com/apt-repo/dists/xenial/InRelease  403  Forbidden [IP: 52.218.80.49 80]
E: The repository 'http://realsense-alm-public.s3.amazonaws.com/apt-repo xenial InRelease' is not signed.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
```

I've tried the --allow--unauthorized (don't remember exact syntax atm) even though I also read it only works with apt-get upgrade (not update). It did not work. Also tried with a brand new image. I've been able to run install on my ubuntu laptop with no problem. I've also been trying to add the repo manually but haven't been able to figure out how to.

Answer (score 2):

*403 - Forbidden* is a server side error. You are not allowed to access the data on the server.

Please, update /etc/apt/sources.list.

Answer (score 1):

As Xypron implied but did not explain what to actually do.  You need to edit the apt package sources that apt (or apt-get) will use.  When I just came across this problem with a old artful release VM and had the same problem as ZJ, I added the lines below to the top of my /etc/apt/sources.list to make it work normally.  Note:

1. You need to use sudo / super user powers to edit this file as it is owned by root.  In my case I used `sudo vim /etc/apt/sources.list` but if you are not familiar with vi/vim then try `sudo nano /etc/apt/sources.list`
2. You will need to know the name of your ubuntu release.  In my case it is `artful` but that may differ for you.  If you do not know then you can tell by looking for similar lines already in you sources.list file to deduce what name to use instead.  The OP should use `bionic` based on his console output text

```
## Use the old releases to try and solve update issues
deb http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ artful main restricted
deb http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ artful-updates main restricted
deb http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ artful universe
deb http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ artful-updates universe
deb http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ artful multiverse
deb http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ artful-updates multiverse
deb http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ artful-backports main restricted universe multiverse
deb http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ artful-security main restricted
deb http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ artful-security universe
deb http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ artful-security multiverse
```

Comment: It would be great if someone who channels the force stronger than me could fix up the suggested insert text.  For some reason the code block would not work when I tried to use it.

Answer (score -3):

Please, update /etc/apt/sources.list.

$ sudo apt-get update

This is not answer!